# Pandas Dataframe MultiIndex transform one level of the multiindex to another axis while keeping the other level in the original axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a Pandas `Dataframe` with `MultiIndex` in the row indexers like this:

[image]

This dataframe is a result of a `groupby` operation and then slicing from a 3-level `MultiIndex`.I would like the 'date' row indexer to remain, but shift the 'SlabType' level of row indexers into column indexer with non-available values as `NaN`.

This is what I would like to get to:

[image]

What operations do I need to do to achieve this? Also if the title of the question can be improved, please suggest so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with select column `SlabLT`:

```
print (df['SlabLT'].unstack())
```

But if possible duplicates in `MultiIndex` is necessary aggregate column, a.g. by `mean`:

```
print (df.groupby(level=[0,1])['SlabLT'].mean().unstack())
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-10-01','2017-10-08','2017-10-08','2017-10-15', '2017-10-15'],
                   'SlabType':['UOM2','AMOUNT','UOM2','AMOUNT','AMOUNT'],
                   'SlabLT':[1,6000,1,6000,5000]}).set_index(['date','SlabType'])

print (df)
                     SlabLT
date       SlabType        
2017-10-01 UOM2           1
2017-10-08 AMOUNT      6000
           UOM2           1
2017-10-15 AMOUNT      6000 <-duplicated MultiIndex '2017-10-15', 'AMOUNT'
           AMOUNT      5000 <-duplicated MultiIndex '2017-10-15', 'AMOUNT'

print (df['SlabLT'].unstack())
```

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

---

```
print (df.groupby(level=[0,1])['SlabLT'].mean())
date        SlabType
2017-10-01  UOM2           1
2017-10-08  AMOUNT      6000
            UOM2           1
2017-10-15  AMOUNT      5500
Name: SlabLT, dtype: int64

print (df.groupby(level=[0,1])['SlabLT'].mean().unstack())
SlabType    AMOUNT  UOM2
date                    
2017-10-01     NaN   1.0
2017-10-08  6000.0   1.0
2017-10-15  5500.0   NaN
```

Comment: unstacking it is working, exactly what I needed, thanks! I am not able to properly understand what you meant to say in the line 'But if possible duplicates...', can you explain that line?

Comment: @SushovanMandal - The best is seen it in sample, give me second.

Comment: @SushovanMandal - Added sample for better explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that, I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `NaN` values for some entries, you may want to consider [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) to avoid "duplicate entries" ValueError when unstacking one of the indices.

Suppose you have `df` DataFrame with column `'SlabLT'` with indices `date` and `SlabType`, try:

`df.reset_index().pivot_table(values = 'SlabLT', index = 'date', columns = 'SlabLT')`

Comment: When does this 'duplicate entries' ValueError arise in 'unstack'?